# How to customize the output with return_trace in erlang trace？

Tags: debugging, erlang, trace

I know the function of  `return_trace` in [erlang trace](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#trace-3):

```
To get trace messages containing return values from functions,
use the {return_trace} match specification action instead.
```

But How can I  customize the  output  if the result too big?

I want it to display the first 100 bytes of the return values.

Answer (score 0):

```
receive
    {trace, Pid, return_from, {Module, Function, Arity}, ReturnValue} ->
        StringReturnValue = io_lib:format("~w", [ReturnValue]),
        First100 = lists:sublist(lists:flatten(StringReturnValue), 1, 100)
        io:format("~p:~p/~p returned: ~p~n", [Module, Function, Arity, First100)
```

If you know the return value is a string (which is the same thing as a list of integers in erlang) then you can write:

```
receive
    {trace, Pid, return_from, {Module, Function, Arity}, ReturnValue} ->
        First100 = lists:sublist(ReturnValue, 1, 100)
        io:format("~p:~p/~p returned: ~p~n", [Module, Function, Arity, First100)
```